# Microsoft flow send email every day at 12:00 PM

Tags: flow

Hi I add to my flow `delay to` to send email:

[image]

When I have only `startOfDay(utcNow())` flow return

> 2019-02-15T00:00:00Z

But I need send email every day at 12:00 PM, so I need add 12 hours to time.
When I added `startOfDay(utcNow(),+12)`, flow return me error:

> You can not process expressions of a template language in the input
>   data of action "Delay_to" in line "1" and column "2579": "For the
>   template language function" startOfDay "it is expected that its second
>   parameter will be of type string. The value provided is of type
>   "Integer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the flow, create trigger **Recurrence**:

- Interval: `1` - Frequency: `Day`
- TimeZone - `Set correct TimeZone`
- Start time: Set Time from which it will be recurred like Tomorrows 12:00: `2019-02-16T12:00:00Z`

After this Trigger you will have your code with sending an email.

[image]

*Hope it helps!*